Fresh download of Eclipse 2024_06 will not launch, complaining of missing SWT library
All I did was unzip and launch Eclipse 2024_06 and it cannot find swt libraries which you would think SHOULD be in one of the plugins.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
C:\cypress\eclipse-2024_06\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\422\0\.cp\swt-win32-4965r11.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
no swt-win32 in java.library.path: C:\cypress\eclipse-2024_06;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/cypress/eclipse-2024_06//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.3.v20240426-1530/jre/bin/server;C:/cypress/eclipse-2024_06//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.3.v20240426-1530/jre/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\wbaldwin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration\;C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\db2\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\db2\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\db2\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\cypress\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\wbaldwin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\cypress\eclipse-2024_06;;.
no swt in java.library.path: C:\cypress\eclipse-2024_06;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/cypress/eclipse-2024_06//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.3.v20240426-1530/jre/bin/server;C:/cypress/eclipse-2024_06//plugins/org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_21.0.3.v20240426-1530/jre/bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\app\wbaldwin\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Sync\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Google Apps Migration\;C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;C:\Program Files (x86)\ibm\gsk8\lib;C:\db2\SQLLIB\BIN;C:\db2\SQLLIB\FUNCTION;C:\db2\SQLLIB\SAMPLES\REPL;C:\cypress\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\jre\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\wbaldwin\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\cypress\eclipse-2024_06;;.
C:\Users\wbaldwin\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4965r11.dll: The specified procedure could not be found
Can't load library: C:\Users\wbaldwin\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll
Can't load library: C:\Users\wbaldwin\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt.dll
C:\Users\wbaldwin\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4965r11.dll: The specified procedure could not be found

here
Also  Can't load library: C:\Users\wbaldwin\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4965r11.dll Can't load library: C:\Users\wbaldwin\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32.dll Can't load library: C:\Users\wbaldwin\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt.dll C:\Users\wbaldwin\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-win32-4965r11.dll: The specified procedure could not be found

This would be a file that is unpacked from one of the included plug-ins. Which download of 2024-06 was this, from where, and unzipped how? Does the disk have free space for unpacking things? Do you have full ownership and file permissions where you unzipped it?

I cannot reproduce what you say. Please improve your question to address all nitind asked. Make also sure to unzip it into an empty directory.

I got the same issue (on Windows 7), but 2024-03 installation worked fine.

Getting the same error on Windows 8.1
